# onfocusin not working for firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-events

I have a Javascript running in a page. The following is the code am using.

```
window.document.onkeydown = keydown;
function keydown()
{ 
  alert("keydown");
}

 window.document.onfocusin = focussedin ;
 function focussedin ()
{ 
   alert("focus in");
 }
```

Here , If I run the code, I am not getting the focus in alert for firefox and chrome. Whether  window.document.onfocusin will not work in other browsers except IE ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onfocusin`  is only supported by  `IE` http://help.dottoro.com/ljggspvo.php

You should use onfocus instead.

```
 function onfocusFun ()
 { 
   console.log("focus in");
 }
 window.onfocus = onfocusFun;
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/X5kD2/)

Note: Behavior of firefox is correct as you loss focus from document once it open alertbox and on closing alertbox you agian firing onfocus. Use console.log instead.

Comment: This illustrates one of the advantages of using JQuery

Comment: I have used onfocus, it works weird. It works fine in firefox(that too focus in alert called too many times), in IE and chrome am not able to get any alerts

Comment: @Perseus use window.onfocus instead of  window.document. It was working for me.

Comment: Hi @Sushil. Am able to call the onfocusfun method, but the problem is , am not able to get the document.activeElement.name